# How to get Application name from iphone App IPA with PHP

Tags: php, iphone, ipa

I need to create a PHP Script get IPA NAME and display on my site.

Is there any possibility to get iPA name..

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give PHP-specific advice, but here's what you need to do:

1. An IPA file is a ZIP file, so the first thing you need to do is extract this file.
2. Inside this ZIP file, at the root level, there's a file named `iTunesMetadata.plist`. This is a binary plist file, which you need to parse (you can probably find a plist library for PHP).
3. Finally, you need to fetch the value for the `itemName` key.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i already did this.. using this code.. https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList

Comment: BUt i need to know how to extract IPA with PHP?

Comment: @Muhammad just Google for php unzip.

Comment: No.. I found this awnser after posting a queastion.. but i need to know how to extra IPA.. dose its use simple ZIP extra method or need some special?

Comment: it's a simple, normal ZIP file. nothing special about it.